# How to remove drag function from ion-menu?

Tags: ionic-framework, angular, ionic2

I'm using ionic 2 and I want to know how to remove drag function from ion-menu ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
this.app.getComponent('leftMenu').isSwipeEnabled = false;
```

Answer (score 6):

**In ionic 2**:

```
ionViewDidEnter() {
    this.menu.swipeEnable(false);
  }
```

check this `swipeEnable(shouldEnable, menuId)` from [ionic v2 docs](https://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/api/components/menu/MenuController/#swipeEnable)

**In ionic 1**:
refer to this [codepen](http://codepen.io/NewbieDev/pen/wMjyEy)

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but it doesn't help me, because drag-content="false" for ionic 1, but I need for ionic 2.

Comment: @Ignat try this in your controller.. `$ionicSideMenuDelegate.canDragContent(false);`

Answer (score 1):

In ionic 2 beta 9, you can add `[swipeEnabled]="false"` in html.

```
<ion-menu [swipeEnabled]="false">
</ion-menu>
```

Answer (score 0):

In your ion-menu add: `swipeEnabled="false"` directive, that would do.

Answer (score 0):

For Ionic 1, look for:

```
<ion-pane ion-side-menu-content>
```

and change it to:

```
<ion-pane ion-side-menu-content drag-content="false">
```

(I know someone else attempted to answer for Ionic 1 already, but it wasn't very clear at all).